# php + webdav to do a 'svn copy url url' command

Tags: php, svn, webdav

I am trying to create an automagic svn 'tag/export' button for moving from our dev-test-stage-live environments.

I am using a slightly modified (fixed) version of phpsvnclient
to send http requests in the webdav format to our jira svn repository.  I'd prefer to not rely on any php library/module and use only core php code to accomplish this.  I'd also prefer to avoid using shell_exec (which I already have working).

The process I am creating is:

1.) Get current environments release tag ($major.$minor.$svn_version)

2.) Increment the $minor #

3.) Get latest version # for /trunk and make that the $svn_version of the new release tag

4.) svn copy /trunk /tags/$new_release_tag

http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc4918.html#copy.for.collections

In step #3, I am able to send a webdav request to get the version # for /trunk, but I do not seem to be able to send the proper webdav command to copy the /trunk collection to /tags/$new_release_tag

I am getting a http response status of 409.

I thought maybe it was expecting a commit message or that I needed to mkcol first.  I can't find documentation for sending a commit message and when I try to MKCOL /tags/$new_release_tag , I also get a 409.

I have an open ticket with Jira studio, but so far their answer is that they don't support 'custom svn clients' :(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to just copy and use [autoversioning](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.webdav.html)

Comment: this does not apply to my use case of making a tagged release copy controlled by an external version number.  I am trying to use the webdav http protocol to communicate with the svn server, I am not implementing a full fledged webdav client.